# AWS Content Type Settings in S3 Using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a web page to an S3 bucket using Amazon's [Boto3 SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) for Python.

I am having trouble setting the `Content-Type`. AWS keeps creating a new metadata key for `Content-Type` in addition to the one I'm specifying using this code:

```
# Upload a new file
data = open('index.html', 'rb')
x = s3.Bucket('website.com').put_object(Key='index.html', Body=data)
x.put(Metadata={'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
```

Any guidance of how to set `Content-Type` to `text/html` would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`Content-Type` isn't *custom* metadata, which is what `Metadata` is used for. It has its own property which can be set like this:

```
bucket.put_object(Key='index.html', Body=data, ContentType='text/html')
```

---

*Note: `.put_object()` can set more than just `Content-Type`. Check out the [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.put_object) for the rest.*

Answer (score 75):

You can also do it with the `upload_file()` method and `ExtraArgs` keyword (and set the permissions to World read as well):

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(
    'source_file_name.html',
    'my.bucket.com',
    'aws_file_name.html',
    ExtraArgs={
        'ContentType': 'application/json',
        'ACL': 'public-read',
    },
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Example using Boto3 -
Use "ExtraArgs" parameter

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name = "us-east-1")
    
s3.upload_file(file_path, s3_bucket, file_name, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/json"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# bucket: s3 bucket name
# key: s3 file path (eg: test/123/a.jpg)
# file_path: local file path
def upload_img(bucket: str, key: str, file_path: str):
    s3_client.upload_file(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Filename=file_path, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "image/jpeg"})
    os.remove(file_path)
    print("upload image {} success".format(file_path))
```

Answer (score -6):

Here, `data` is an opened file, not its content:

> ```
> # Upload a new file
> data = open('index.html', 'rb')
> ```

To read a (binary) file:

```
import io

with io.open("index.html", mode="rb") as fd:
    data = fd.read()
```

It will be better that way.

Comment: Thanks for your message.  It is still uploading as "binary/octet-stream" though.