# adding metadata in Image file created from base64 string javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, amazon-s3, base64

I have an existing code which converts base64 string to corresponding image file. Now, I want to add some metadata like last modified date, photographer, copyright, credits etc. **Tried below which did not work**. Is there a way I could add the metadata?

here base64Source is the dataUri from which I am getting base 64 content.

```
function (base64Source, name) {
        var base64Content = base64Source.substr(base64Source.indexOf(',') + 1);

        var byteString = window.atob(base64Content);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var file = new Blob([ia], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
        return new File([the_file], name);
    };
```

I modified this piece of code as

```
function (base64Source, name) {
        var base64Content = base64Source.substr(base64Source.indexOf(',') + 1);

        var byteString = window.atob(base64Content);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var file = new Blob([ia], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
        return new File([the_file], name,{
            lastModified: new Date().getTime(), 
            tooltip : 'test tooltip',
            caption : 'test caption',
            copyright : 'Test',
            credits : 'Test'
        });
    };
```

Comment: Would something like https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs be helpful?

Comment: Thanks Luke. But, I need to create the file with updated metadata and save it in some s3

Comment: This is an [tag:amazon-s3] question. I don't know the specifics of s3, but metadata should be POSTed either with headers or URL parameters.

Comment: I want the file's metadata to be updated like photographer, copyright etc not the s3 metadata as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292005/aws-s3-image-saving-loses-metadata

Comment: @user123475 - did you ever find a solution? if so please do share

Answer (score 1):

These metadata should be part of the file's data itself.

The javascript File object will not change the file's data <sub>(apart from the EOL `endings` option of the [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) that File does inherit from)</sub>.

So you'd have to actually modify your file's data (i.e the bytes contained in `ia`'s ArrayBuffer).

The way you will do it depends on the type of image you are dealing with. Different image formats have different rules as to what metadata they can accept and how it should be stored in the file.

For instance, for JPEG files, TIFF and webp formats it is common to have it in [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data, stored in an *Application Segment*, identifiable by the `0xFFE1` marker for JPEG. [webp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#metadata) marks it with a [`chunkHeader('EXIF')`](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#riff_file_format). They also all support [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform).
PNG also allows some [text-info](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo) metadata.

Other file formats may support other metadata formats, and writing you an universal encoder would be ... a very hard work.

But some libraries do exist for the most common formats (JPEG's EXIF ones are easily found using your favorite web search tool).

Comment: Thanks Kaiido for detail explanation. I need to update the image metadata as I am generating the image after cropping the original image. I used <img-crop> directive to crop the image which is loosing the original image metadata. Do you see any better approach?