# Update a static webpage in S3 bucket with Python/boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to find another article with my question but I failed.

My end goal is to upload an html file into an S3 bucket that is configured to host a static webpage.
I have tried with:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
```

and

```
with open("index.html", "rb") as f:
   s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, "index.html")
```

With both approaches, I successfully upload the html file. Nonetheless, when I access the URL instead of displaying the html file, it downloads it.

I can verify that the S3 bucket is configured to host a webpage and to display the file with the same name like the one I upload using Python. When I upload the file manually from my folder, it works as expected. When I push the file using Python instead of displaying it, it downloads it as mentioned above.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is the 2 x functions I tried not appropriate for the work I need to do? Do you think there is any misconfiguration on the S3 bucket?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think `content-type` is not set correctly.

Comment: Hello Marcin,

The content-type should be set on the Python script or a configuration on the S3 bucket?

Thanks

Comment: Its object-level property. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550816/aws-content-type-settings-in-s3-using-boto3) for example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcin Indeed it was the content-type. I am using the following command now and it works fine
s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file,ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'text/html'})

Comment: Good to hear. I added the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the problem was incorrect/lack of `text/html` content type for the objects uploaded. The solution was to add it.