# How to view S3 bucket video files into browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my current project, my objective is  to access the video files (in `mp4`) from AWS S3 bucket.
I have created S3 bucket, named  `videostreambucketpankesh` . This is a public folder with the following permission (as follows).

[image]

The Access Control list (ACL) of `videostreambucketpankesh` bucket  is as follows:

[image]

The bucket policy of `videostreambucketpankesh` bucket  is as follows:
[image]

Now the bucket  “`videostreambucketpankesh`” contains many subfolders (or sub-buckets), including one subfolder, named “`video`”. This sub-bucket contains some `.mp4` file (as shown in the image below).

[image]

My problem is that there are some files (such as `firetruck.mp4` and `ambulance.mp4`) that can be directly accessed by browser, when I click its `objectURL`. I can play them in the browser.

However, I am not able to play **other `.mp4`**  ( `39cf9079-7b65-4aa8-8913-8a6b924021d3.mp4, 45fd1749-95aa-488c-ac2f-be8673b8416e.mp4, 8ba187f2-5148-49f6-9acc-2459e41f547b.mp4`) files into the browser, when I click its objectURL.

Please note that I upload `39cf9079-7b65-4aa8-8913-8a6b924021d3.mp4, 45fd1749-95aa-488c-ac2f-be8673b8416e.mp4, 8ba187f2-5148-49f6-9acc-2459e41f547b.mp4` video file using a python program **programmatically** in Python (See the following code ).

```
def upload_to_s3(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    data = open(local_file, 'rb')
    s3_client.put_object(Key="video/"+frame_id+".mp4", Body=data, ContentType='video/mp4', Bucket = s3_bucket)
    print("Upload succcessful")
```

**However, I am not able to play mp4 file  (I play them in VLC player) in my Google chrome browser.** **Can you please suggest how can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the files and look at **Properties / Metadata**.

It should show `Content-Type : video/mp4` like this:

[image: Amazon S3 object metadata]

When uploading via the browser, the metadata is automatically set based upon the filetype.

If you are uploading via your own code, you can set the metadata like this:

```py
s3_client.upload_file('video.mp4', bucketname, key, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "video/mp4"})

or

bucket.put_object(key, Body=data, ContentType='video/mp4')
```

See: [AWS Content Type Settings in S3 Using Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34550816/174777)

Comment: Thank you so much John! As per your suggestion, I have revised my Python file with "Content-Type" : video/mp4". I can see the video file properties "Content-type": 'video/mp4" is changed now.  However, I am still not able to play my mp4 files into Google Chrome Browser.  Please suggest!!! Thank you so much again for your help!!!!

Comment: Take a look at the metadata on the files that _do_ work and compare them to the ones that _don't_ work. See if you can find a difference. Also, download the files and try playing them on your computer to confirm that the files contain correct video data.

Comment: Thank you so much John for your help! it has been fixed now.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I've had issues uploading a video file in Postman as a form-data parameter - it was corrupted since the file content type was set to application/octet-stream. Instead, upload the file as a Binary. Exported curl: 

curl --location --request PUT 'https://yourbucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/video.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=valueAndOtherParameters' \
--header 'Content-Type: video/mp4' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/user/Downloads/video.mp4"'