# AWS Lambda - generating PDF issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'd like to generate a pdf file using AWS Lambda, put it in the S3 bucket and distribute it later to a specific group of recipients. I have managed to generate and upload the pdf to the S3 bucket, however after I manually download the pdf, I cannot open it as the file seems to be corrupted/protected (the size is greater than 0B though, so I expect the information is saved to the file).

**Edit: Added full Lambda function**

Below the relevant code fragment :

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10**2,3)), columns = ("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"))
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,colLabels=df.columns,loc='center')

    
    path = "/tmp/doc.pdf"
    pp = PdfPages(path)
    pp.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
    
 
    s = boto3.client('s3')
    s.upload_file(path, 'bucket_name', 'doc.pdf')
    

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: The code that you provided, is it lambda function? If so, it is incomplete and incorrect code for a lambda function.

Comment: You code will not create a PDF document

Comment: TO create a PDF from a Lambda function,  you need to use a third party API such as Apache PDFBox.

Answer (score 1):

While there are many missing compoenents to your question, and few concepts being taken in an incorrect manner - allow me to guide you a bit.

1. AWS Lambda: [From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html)

`AWS Lambda is a compute service that lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers`

Clearly, it is not a mechanism that could "generate" PDF. However, if you have a code that  can "generate" PDF, you can use AWS Lambda service to execute it on the cloud.

2. Your code: Looks like this bit you have got it covered.
3. Corrupt PDF on download: Can you try renaming the file with a `.pdf` extension and then try opening it? If this works, you can add a `Content-Type` header while uploading the file to S3 to mark it as a PDF file. More information in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550816/aws-content-type-settings-in-s3-using-boto3)

Comment: I tried renaming, but it didn't work, the ExtraArgs piece can be useful though. I've added full code above.

Comment: The code that actually does the "making and saving PDF" - can you try and run it locally (directly run as a python script) and check if you get a valid working PDF?

Comment: Yes, tried it locally and it works, which is a bit confusing. I don't think it's a permission issue too, since I uploaded a csv file to the same bucket and was able to download and open it.

Comment: If it was a permission issue you would not be able to download at all. Maybe look at the type of file getting downloaded?