# how to specify ContentType for S3 files?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I am trying to convert files to gzip files and then upload them to S3. When I check in S3, the files are there but they don't have a type specified. How can I specify the content type?

```
    for i in testList:
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            source_file = stack.enter_context(open(i , mode="rb"))
            destination_file = io.BytesIO()
            destination_file_gz = stack.enter_context(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file, mode='wb'))
            while True:
                chunk = source_file.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                destination_file_gz.write(chunk)
            destination_file_gz.close()
            destination_file.seek(0)
            
            bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName, ContentType='application/gzip')
```

If I add ContentType as an argument to the last line, I get an error:

```
"errorMessage": "bucket_upload_fileobj() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ContentType'",
```

Comment: Try `ExtraArgs={'Content-Type': 'application/gzip'}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
bucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file, fileName,ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/gzip"})
```

See [AWS Content Type Settings in S3 Using Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550816/aws-content-type-settings-in-s3-using-boto3)

Comment: this doesn't throw an error but the type is still undefined in S3

Comment: you can try also upload_file() where you set the filename so your code is much simpler  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file