# Image file type is not supported when downloading using urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, urllib3

hi I am downloading image like this

```
import urllib3     

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/192/536/354.png?hmac=a22QkdSZ7zXUHpV4-gnB48PPYaLlcvaTMeDXxcPRxs8')
print(r.data)
```

then uploading it to s3 using this

```
 s3 = boto3.resource(s3')
    key = 'file_name + '.png'    
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(r.data), key)
```

but when I open I get error on image opening "File type is not supported "  when I open using photo opener

```
**EDIT:** I did as suggested by passing
 ContentType='text/png'
```

and when I opening image by url getting this on aws : I opened this using presinged url

[image]

Comment: You need to set the content-type when you upload to s3. S3 does not detect it automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34550816/1032785

Comment: @jordanm so In my case  ContentType='text/plain' ? and do I need to convert it to base64?

Comment: You want `image/jpeg` as the content-type.

Comment: @jordanm still not :(

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you're downloading a `jpg` file and uploading it as a `png` file? That doesn't make sense. If that's not what you're actually doing, I'd suggest updating the question to correct it. It would also be useful to see what your latest iteration is that is still not working as you hoped.

Comment: @Erwin thanks for indicating updated question with .jpeg as In real scenario I am doing with jpeg.

Comment: Can you also upload the question with your most recent attempt, where you try to set the content type as you upload to S3?

Comment: @Erwin question updated sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not actually mention how you add the `ContentType`. This is working example, using `boto3.resource()`

```python
bucketname = <my-bucket>
filename   = <filename>

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
key = 'image.png'
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
with open(filename, "rb") as fd:
    bucket.upload_fileobj(
        fd,
        Key=key,
        ExtraArgs={
            "ContentType": "image/png",
        }
    )
```

I then generate a pre-signed URL (which you didn't include, but as long as you get the permissions right, I'm sure you're fine)

```python
expiration = 3600
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  region_name='us-east-2',
                  config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
response = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucketname,
        'Key': key
    },
    ExpiresIn=expiration
)
print(response)
```

Opening the resulting URL in my browser, it loads the PNG image that I uploaded.